# Aliasing generic function with specific types

Tags: typescript

Say I have a generic function `b`. I'd love to be able to do the following:

```
const a = b<X, Y, Z>;
```

such that `a(p, q, r) === b<X, Y, Z>(p, q, r)`.

How can I achieve this?

One way I know of is to do something like `const a = <X, Y, Z>(...props) => b<X, Y, Z>(...props)`, but then I also have to specify the types of `props` as iterable, etc., and I wa hoping for something a little more elegant

---

Specifically, I am looking to do the following:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const createSpecificThunk = createAsyncThunk<ResponseType, PropsType>;

// Then, `... = createAsyncThunk<ResponseType, PropsType>(...)`
// should equal `... = createSpecificThunk(...)`
```

I've realised for my case I could just do the following:

```
const createSpecificThunk = (actionType: string, callback: (props: X) => Y) => (
  createAsyncThunk<X, Y>(actionType, callback)
);
```

because the first type represents the return type, and the second type represents the props type! But I'm still curious if the above can be done for generic

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've updated the question to specifically include the intent, but to further clarify for my case `a` is `createAsyncThunk`, and I want `b` to represent `createAsyncThunk` with its generic types defined

Comment: I don't know whether you can do that in the *general* case where you don't know how the type parameters are used. You can probably do it in specific cases. For instance, if you know that `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are the types of parameters the function takes, you can do this: `const a: (p1: string, p2: number, p3: boolean) => ReturnType<typeof b> = b;`. And of course you can always create a *wrapper* function. For instance, if the target function takes three type params but just one function parameter which is (picking at random) `Y`, you can...

Comment: ...do: `const a = (arg: string) => b<number, string, boolean>(arg);` But that's a wrapper, not assigning `b` to `a`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay. So if I'm following correctly, that means the last edit in my question is as good as I can get?

Comment: Well, unless the type parameters are all used by parameters or the return value, in which case you could do the first thing I listed above instead (with a specific type instead of `ReturnType<typeof b>` if `b`'s return type is one of the type parameters). But for the second case where they aren't mapped to parameters/return value, I'm saying *I don't know* whether you can do better than a wrapper. :-)

Comment: Also I think `createAsyncThunk(actionType, callback)` will be enough in your last example as generic params will be inferred from `callback` type

Comment: @AlekseyL. The parameters to the wrapper will unfortunately be of type `any` if I don't specify them

Comment: Ooh, TS4.7 will support this with *instantiation expressions* as implemented in [ms/TS#47607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607); see [here, using TS4.7 nightly build](https://tsplay.dev/wOJvdW).  Before then you will have a hard time wrangling something that works and a wrapper is probably the easiest solution.  Do you want me to write up an answer for this?

Comment: @jcalz That would be absolutely amazing, what a find!

Answer (score 1):

Before TypeScript 4.7, you could only specify the type parameters of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function when you actually call the function:

```
declare function foo<T>(x: T): T[]; // generic function

let strArr = foo<string>("hello"); // specify T when calling
// const strArr: string[]
let numArr = foo<number>(123); // specify T when calling
// const numArr: number[]
```

And while the compiler could verify that a generic function is always assignable to a non-generic version where the type parameters have been specified:

```
let bar: (x: string) => string[] = foo; // okay
let baz: (x: number) => number[] = foo; // okay
```

you would still have to do this *manually*.  There was no way to say "`bar` is like `foo` when you instantiate `T` with `string`".  So you'd have to resort to wrapper functions or other clunky workarounds:

```
bar = (x: string) => foo(x); // wrapper, okay
```

---

But TypeScript 4.7 will introduce *instantiation expressions*, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607), "which provide the ability to specify type arguments for generic functions or generic constructors without actually calling them":

```
bar = foo<string>; // okay in TS4.7+
baz = foo<number>; // okay in TS4.7+
```

So once that lands you'll be able to write your code exactly as desired:

```
const createSpecificThunk = createAsyncThunk<ResponseType, PropsType>;  // okay TS4.7+

/* const createSpecificThunk: (
    typePrefix: string, 
    payloadCreator: AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<ResponseType, PropsType, {}>, 
    options?: AsyncThunkOptions<PropsType, {}> | undefined
) => AsyncThunk<ResponseType, PropsType, {}> */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.0-dev.20220302#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-VBHSUVLL4L6WW1BfaxpjjNis5LPZIFHBTe8aLMnamMAAvDOxt3xnPYuMBgumL0QYuliDlgj0tPK0wCoZWzVN1UC40ls09itJgeFtVZorTsuzOCjIXeAAsADoAOwAalUaeri-iLcDXZnvY3XNIO4Ph6AA)